# Exporting FEATURE_FLAG recursively to makefiles, CPP and Header files

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

1. FEATURE_FLAG is applicable to *feature_folder* - being newly introduced in the build system based on below condition in the top level makefile.

   ifdef FEATURE_AAA
   export FEATURE_FLAG=0
   else
   export FEATURE_FLAG=1
2. CPP and Header files inside the *feature_folder* further include some headers based on FEATURE_FLAG as below.

e.g. foo.cpp includes foo.h which has-

```
//Code
#if FEATURE_FLAG
#include <cstring>
#endif
//Code
a = memset(...);
//Code
```

3. With the $(warning ...) prints in the makefiles corresponding to foo.cpp and foo.h, I have ensured that FEATURE_FLAG=1 just right before foo.cpp gets compiled. This means, the FEATURE_FLAG=1 setting works fine in the contained makefiles.

**However, foo.cpp compilation gives the error as - memset not found.**

**If I comment the FEATURE_FLAG in the foo.h and include the cstring as default, the compilation works ok.**

Q => Why doesn't the foo.h "see" the FEATURE_FLAG being set to 1?

**CXX := arm-5.3-uclibc-1.0.12/usr/bin/arm-linux-g++

CC := arm-5.3-uclibc-1.0.12/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc**

Comment: Please take a few minutes after asking a question to read through it and examine its formatting, and if it's not formatted properly, edit the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the make variable `FEATURE_FLAG`.  Make variables exist in your makefile, they do not exist (automatically) in your compiler when it compiles your code.

If you want to pass a value from your makefile into the compiler as a C or C++ preprocessor macro definition, you have to put it on the compiler's command line using the `-D` option.

You don't show enough of your makefile to be able to give exact instructions but assuming that you have a make variable `CPPFLAGS` that contains preprocessor definitions, you would do something like this:

```
CPPFLAGS += -DFEATURE_FLAG=$(FEATURE_FLAG)
```